# What is the required DataFlavor to copy files in Mac OSX

Tags: java, macos, copy-paste

I'm currently working on Java code that can copy files into the system clipboard.

For Windows and Linux I already got it working. For OSX I tried several flavors but the "Paste" action in Finder never cames active.

Any idea which DataFlavor settings are required for Finder?

Used flavors:

```
DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor
URILIST_FLAVOR = new DataFlavor( "text/uri-list" );
XFILELIST_FLAVOR = new DataFlavor( "application/x-java-file-list" );
GNOMEFILELIST_FLAVOR = new DataFlavor( "x-special/gnome-copied-files" );
```

The method to return the data for the flavor:

```
public Object getTransferData( DataFlavor flavor ) throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
    if( FILELIST_FLAVOR.equals( flavor ) ) {
        if( List.class == flavor.getRepresentationClass() ) {
            return Arrays.asList( files );
        } else if( InputStream.class == flavor.getRepresentationClass() ) {
            return getStreamData( files, null );
        }
    } else if( DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor.equals( flavor ) ) {
        if( List.class == flavor.getRepresentationClass() ) {
            return locallist;
        } else if( InputStream.class == flavor.getRepresentationClass() ) {
            return getStreamData( files, null );
        }
    } else if( URILIST_FLAVOR.equals( flavor ) ) {
        if( List.class == flavor.getRepresentationClass() ) {
            return Arrays.asList( files );
        } else if( InputStream.class == flavor.getRepresentationClass() ) {
            return getStreamData( files, null );
        }
    } else if( GNOMEFILELIST_FLAVOR.equals( flavor ) ) {
        if( List.class == flavor.getRepresentationClass() ) {
            return Arrays.asList( files );
        } else if( InputStream.class == flavor.getRepresentationClass() ) {
            // FIXME support cut and copy
            return getStreamData( files, "copy" );
        }
    } else if( XFILELIST_FLAVOR.equals( flavor ) ) {
        if( List.class == flavor.getRepresentationClass() ) {
            return locallist;
        } else if( InputStream.class == flavor.getRepresentationClass() ) {
            return getStreamData( files, null );
        }
    }
    throw new UnsupportedFlavorException( flavor );
}
```

Thanks,
André

Answer (score 1):

I did a small investigation and here is the answer:

It should work with

```
DataFlavor#javaFileListFlavor
```

but the copy-paste functionality for files is broken on the native side for all JDKs that are based on OpenJDK.

The OpenJDK implementation uses `NSPasteboard.sendData` method with the format `NSFilenamesPboardType`. Unfortunately, NSFilenamesPboardType [is deprecated and removed after 10.14](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsfilenamespboardtype).
So the functionality worked in 10.13 and before but is broken after the version.

There are a couple of possible solutions:

1. I've found the [NSPasteboardAPI](https://github.com/TimmyOVO/NSPasteboardAPI) library that provides proper native API. [Here](https://github.com/TimmyOVO/CopyToFinder) is the java implementation based on the library.
2. I've fixed the problem in the [JetBrains Runtime](https://github.com/JetBrains/JetBrainsRuntime) on the native side so it just works with `DataFlavor#javaFileListFlavor` as you expected.

It is funny that the problem exists for ~10 years at this moment.
I believe it will be also fixed in some upcoming OpenJDK versions, but I am not sure when.

Comment: Maybe you could open a bug report - unless there already is one (I didn't check)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try [DataFlavor#javaFileListFlavor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/DataFlavor.html#javaFileListFlavor).

Excerpt from the API documentation:

**DataFlavor#javaFileListFlavor** ([Link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/DataFlavor.html#javaFileListFlavor))

> To transfer a list of files to/from Java (and the underlying platform) a DataFlavor of this type/subtype and representation class of java.util.List is used. Each element of the list is required/guaranteed to be of type java.io.File.

Comment: by the way ... the result of `System.out.println(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor.getMimeType());` is `application/x-java-file-list; class=java.util.List`

Comment: Please see my question: javaFileListFlavor is already handled. The Finder does not use this flavor.

Comment: Oh ... that seems pretty strange, indeed.