# DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor and Mac OS X clipboard

Tags: java, macos, drag-and-drop, copy-paste

I'm implementing drag-and-drop and copy/paste file export in a Java application that needs to run on Mac OS, Windows, and Linux. I've got a Transferable implementation that handles `DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor` and I've managed to get drag-and-drop working well so far.

But I'm stuck on copy/paste export. While hunting around I found an answer that I thought might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31798747

Indeed, this works on Windows, but not on Mac OS, where I develop, and I think that's the problem, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it.

I also found an old unanswered question from someone who I think was struggling with the same problem, but I think their conclusion that Mac OS Finder doesn't handle `DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor` isn't quite right: [What is the required DataFlavor to copy files in Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3228619)

1. I can drag-and-drop into the Mac OS Finder, desktop, or other applications that accept drop events from files. So clearly Mac OS *can* handle `javaFileListFlavor`.
2. I can also import from the system clipboard by copy-pasting out of Finder into my application (by handling `javaFileListFlavor`), so clearly the clipboard provides something that Java can interpret as `javaFileListFlavor`.
3. I set a breakpoint and looked at  `ClipboardTransferable.getTransferDataFlavors()` and `javaFileListFlavor` is there, along with a whole bunch of other flavors, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

I suspect I need to provide handling for a different flavor to allow the clipboard to handle files from Java. But I don't have any idea what that flavor would be, or how to go about figuring this out.